Does Ukraine consider itself to be at war with North Korea?
North Korea has now sent more than 10,000 North Korean soldiers to fight Ukraine. Reuters (2024-11-12):

Over 10,000 DPRK (North Korean) soldiers have been sent to eastern Russia, and most of them have moved to the far western Kursk Oblast, where they have begun engaging in combat operations with Russian forces.

Bloomberg (2024-11-17):

North Korea may deploy as many as 100,000 troops

Does Ukraine consider itself to be at war with North Korea?
(I believe being at war would mean Ukraine can legitimately attack North Korean military targets, including Kim Jong Un?)

Do the North Korean soldiers already take part in active fighting?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution According to Ukraine: Yes. https://edition.cnn.com/2024/11/07/europe/zelensky-north-korean-troops-russia-putin-intl-hnk/index.html  https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/c14le0p4310o

And what shall "be at war" mean for the purpose of this question? If for for example deadly exchange of fire is meant, then Ukraine basically acknowledges this in the cited source.

Does it matter? Even if they did would they actually be able to attack considering the relative position of both countries?

Keep in mind that, as of the last several decades, formal declarations of war are very much the exception.  Most wars are carried out "off the books", making the distinction rather moot.

Are any North Korean soldiers in Ukraine?  As far as I've read, they've so far been fighting on Russian territory only.

Foreign volunteers/mercenaries have been fighting on Ukraine's side years before the first talks about North Korean soldiers begun. Are those countries at war with Russia?

@gerrit And even this is just an Ukrainian claim without proofs.

@vsz There is an important difference between mercenaries and soldiers ordered to go as part of their military duties.

@vsz And also for military observers getting an idea of the on the ground nuances of action activities for future reference, advisers might be a little more provocative but if not in actions themself typically ignored.

To my knowledge (and as of this date), neither Ukraine nor North Korea has declared war on the other.
Russia has a somewhat unusual military structure. Conscripted soldiers are not allowed to fight outside of Russian borders, so the Russian expeditionary forces (forces fighting in Ukraine or elsewhere) are made up of paid volunteers and mercenaries, and Russia has no overt restrictions on the nationality of those who serve (possibly a remnant of Soviet practice). Russia seems to have entered into a cooperative venture with North Korea in which the latter supplies Russia with arms and soldiers, but the supplied soldiers would technically be considered attached to the Russian military, not operating as North Korean soldiers.
They're effectively loaners; no declaration of war needed. Though I'm not sure Russia will return them in 'like new' condition…

More info: Foreign fighters in the Russo-Ukrainian War. Also, declaring war against North Korea would actually be counter-productive to Ukrainian interest as North Korea has a million strong army; and declaring war would give the North Korean army a valid excuse to more freely actively participate in joint military operations with the Russian military in "self-defence".

I'm somewhat surprised the Russians don't maneuver around the conscription issue by claiming that Ukraine is really part of Russia anyway.

@SoronelHaetir, Putin's been trying, but even with his control of the media, he's having a hard time getting people to accept it.

the supplied soldiers would technically be considered attached to the Russian military, not operating as North Korean soldiers. Is this not at odds with the top answer here: Why is sending troops different from sending military equipment?

@user182601: No, for two reasons: (1) That question refers to Russia's reaction, and Russia has explicit, long-standing policy that an attack by any NATO nation is an attack by NATO. Ukraine has no similar policy towards anyone. (2) That answer is talking about (its example) Polish troops acting under Polish command as part of the Polish army, but in Ukraine. It doesn't consider Polish units detached from the Polish army, entirely under the command of and supplied by Ukraine.

@user182601: Mercenary soldiers have a loooong tradition of acting independently of their official state: Wagner Group operated independently of Russia despite its deep ties to the regime; Blackwater operates independently of the US;  Hessians served the British military in the 18th century; the English White Company in Italy in the 14th century, the 10,000 from ancient Greek history… It's the difference between sending soldiers under your state's control, or farming soldiers  out to other states for their use.

Your answer is to a different question ("Have Ukraine or North Korea declared war on each other?"). My Q is Does Ukraine consider itself to be at war with North Korea? What is your answer to my Q?

@user182601: Nations don't 'consider themselves to be at war'. They declare war, or they don't. They haven't declared war on North Korea, North Korea hasn't declared war on them, so they're not at war.

Russia has officially annexed Donetsk, Kherson, Luhansk, Zaporizhzhia, Crimea, and parts of Mykolaiv, considering all part of Russia, so how is this restriction on conscripted soldiers relevant from Russians point of view?

@SoronelHaetir they do. They held "elections" in several parts of Ukraine that were prearranged to have those parts choose to be a part of Russia. And of course Russia has been claiming for over a century that Ukraine is part of Russia.

@gerrit in reality Russian conscripts are no doubt everywhere. The main reason for the restriction is sending conscripts into foreign military missions for foreign peacetime deployments. The Ukraine operation is classed by Russia as a "liberation of foreign occupied territory" (they consider the entire Ukraine to be occupied by foreigners) and thus the entire Ukraine to be part of Russia. So they can use all the conscripts they want. If they don't that's more to do with the Russian armed forces knowing the quality of their conscripts very well to be utterly useless for anything useful.

@jwenting: Don't underestimate the politics involved here. Moving (young, inexperienced) conscripts into the active war in Ukraine is likely to create significant amounts of popular unrest at home, which Putin can ill-afford.

@TedWrigley which is one reason they're mostly used to fill in positions left open by professionals being sent to the front lines. Which will at some point end when they run out of trained professionals or when the powers that be start sending conscript units close enough to the front to come under Ukrainian bombardment but still technically outside Ukraine.

@TedWrigley Declaring wars is coming somewhat out of fashion in the last ~ 70 years. Especially for the conflict we are talking about, neither side seems to have declared war (and Russia even avoided calling it that for a long time). Still Ukraine considers itself at war with Russia (not sure about the current russian view), so the question whether Ukraine considers itself at war with North Korea is certainly valid.

@PaŭloEbermann:  Actually, Ukraine does not refer to its conflict with Russia as a war, but as the actions of a 'terrorist state', so there's no indication that Ukraine 'believes' itself to be at war with Russia. Though I shouldn't have to point this out, states are not entities capable of 'believing', 'considering', 'feeling', etc: they have no brains or minds. The leaders of states can formally put the state at war, or they can pursue military objectives without formally declaring war, but the state itself doesn't have some private opinion on the matter that we can investigate.

One could equally ask whether the US and the EU consider themselves in war with Russia - these take part by supplying weapons, training of troops, and financial support to Ukraine, but legally none of them formally declared a war on Russia and most didn't break diplomatic relationships with it (a usual reminder is that the US haven't declared a war on anyone since WW2, there is also a nuance between declaring a war on somebody and declaring a state of war.)
As far as Ukraine and the Democratic People's Republic of Korea are concerned, Ukraine has broken diplomatic relationships with the latter over the recognition of the separatist republics in eastern Ukraine, soon after the beginning of the military conflict with Russia:

Relations were suspended in July 2022 due to the North Korea's recognition of the separatist Donetsk People's Republic and Luhansk People's Republic in eastern Ukraine.

Note however, that there is no formal declaration of war between Russia and Ukraine either:

No formal declaration of war has been issued in the ongoing Russo-Ukrainian War. When Putin announced the Russian invasion of Ukraine, he claimed to commence a "special military operation", side-stepping a formal declaration of war. The statement was, however, regarded by the Ukrainian government as a declaration of war and reported as such by many international news sources. While the Ukrainian parliament refers to Russia as a "terrorist state" in regard to its military actions in Ukraine, it has not issued a formal declaration of war on its behalf.

(emphasis is mine)

North Korea did not send 10,000 soldiers to fight Ukraine.
North Korea did send 10,000 soldiers to defend Russia, if ukrainian soldiers entered Russia's Kursk oblast and suddenly discovered they are fighting north korean soldiers instead russian soldiers - that is still only russian problems how to defend itself.
If north korean soldiers invade territory of Ukraine President of Ukraine according to Constitution of Ukraine have an obligation to declare war, but he already swallowed Russian invasion without such declaration.
If President of Ukraine declares war on North Korea somehow North Korea officials will not bother themselves with answering that as they consider ukrainian president's term expired and any his declarations void.

"North Korea did not send 10,000 soldiers to fight Ukraine. North Korea did send 10,000 soldiers to defend Russia" - that feels like petty semantics, and not really relevant to the overarching question. "If north korean soldiers invade territory of Ukraine President of Ukraine according to Constitution of Ukraine have an obligation to declare war, but he already swallowed Russian invasion without such declaration." - source? "North Korea officials [...] consider ukrainian president's term expired and any his declarations void" - again, source?

So then an active NATO military force on Ukrainian soil would not present a problem by this logic? ;-)

your answer need sources as asked by @F1Krazy. I have not found an obligation of Ukrainian President to declare war. It would be counter-intuitive to declare war as Ukraine did not initiate it in the first place. As per president's mandate expired (I am not sure "term" would be a correct word here) - no it has not. It will expire when a new President is elected (Article 108 of the Constitution). As per what NK officials consider - proof is required.

https://rm.coe.int/constitution-of-ukraine/168071f58b
article 106 part 19 - if there is external aggression
article 103 first part - five year term and that is all, no more

@IvanBorsuk I don't see what that has to do with North Korea-Ukraine relations. No government said "Biden wasn't elected properly, therefore we can ignore his decisions." Nobody ignored Hitler on the grounds he wasn't the proper leader of the Weimar Republic. If North Korea ignored Zelenskyy, that would be an excuse, not a reason.

@IvanBorsuk 1) Ukraine has been under martial law since the invasion. Article 19.1 of Ukraine's martial law code prohibits presidential elections while under martial law. 2) Article 106.19 of the Constitution does not require a declaration of war, it lists it as one of the president's powers.

no elections - no president, what do you not understand about the statement that elected president can be president for only five years? article 106.19 does not describe declaration of war alone, it regulates declaration of war AND external aggression AND usage of armed forces, and, according to your logic you can have clearly defined external aggressor, declare war on extraterresterials and use arny against emus
